# Gradlew Daemon can't reserve enough Heap space tho the RAM is empty enough

Tags: java, minecraft, gradlew, minecraft-forge

As I started with modding Minecraft, I downloaded the Forge sources of 1.7.10, 1.10.2, 1.11.2 and 1.12.2. The command for eclipse was "gradlew setupDecompWorkspace eclipse" which worked fine for the 1.7.10 Forge. When I wanted to do it for the other Versions, there was the Error of not enough Heap Space (3G) but i had about 4G free. I saved two errors. One made with the --stacktrace argument, the other one with --debug. I have 32 and 54Bit Java installed, and tried several solutions from the web. As nothing helped, I'm asking here, with my personal Debug Error code from 1.10.2 Forge.

```
16:52:48.098 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.services.NativeServices] Native-platform posix files is not available.  Continuing with fallback.

16:52:48.125 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.filesystem.services.FileSystemServices] Using JDK 7 file service org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.filesystem.jdk7.WindowsJdk7Symlink

16:52:49.159 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.SingleUseDaemonClient] To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.14/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.

16:52:49.212 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter] Using daemon args: [C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe, -Xmx3G, -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252, -Duser.country=DE, -Duser.language=de, -Duser.variant, -cp, C:\Users\Sebastian\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.14-bin\76oc0mnc3ieqtsukq90mp0rxk\gradle-2.14\lib\gradle-launcher-2.14.jar]

16:52:49.220 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter] Starting daemon process: workingDir = C:\Users\Sebastian\.gradle\daemon\2.14, daemonArgs: [C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe, -Xmx3G, -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252, -Duser.country=DE, -Duser.language=de, -Duser.variant, -cp, C:\Users\Sebastian\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.14-bin\76oc0mnc3ieqtsukq90mp0rxk\gradle-2.14\lib\gradle-launcher-2.14.jar, org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon, 2.14]

16:52:49.248 [INFO] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Starting process 'Gradle build daemon'. Working directory: C:\Users\Sebastian\.gradle\daemon\2.14 Command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe -Xmx3G -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=DE -Duser.language=de -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\Sebastian\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.14-bin\76oc0mnc3ieqtsukq90mp0rxk\gradle-2.14\lib\gradle-launcher-2.14.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 2.14

16:52:49.249 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Environment for process 'Gradle build daemon': {USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=DESKTOP-67RGPD7, PROCESSOR_LEVEL=16, SESSIONNAME=Console, ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData, PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86, PSModulePath=C:\Users\Sebastian\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules, SystemDrive=C:, DIRNAME=C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\Modding\forge\forge-1.10.2-12.18.3.2511-mdk\, USERNAME=Sebastian, CMD_LINE_ARGS=setupDecompWorkspace eclipse --debug, ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86), FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING=Default, APP_HOME=C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\Modding\forge\forge-1.10.2-12.18.3.2511-mdk\, PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.CPL, DriverData=C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData, PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432=AMD64, ProgramData=C:\ProgramData, ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files, HOMEPATH=\Users\Sebastian, PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=AMD64 Family 16 Model 2 Stepping 3, AuthenticAMD, ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files (x86), PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public, windir=C:\Windows, =::=::\, _SKIP=2, LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\Sebastian\AppData\Local, MSMPI_BIN=C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\, USERDOMAIN=DESKTOP-67RGPD7, FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING=Internet Explorer, LOGONSERVER=\\DESKTOP-67RGPD7, JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_181, PROMPT=$P$G, OneDrive=C:\Users\Sebastian\OneDrive, =C:=C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\Modding\forge\forge-1.10.2-12.18.3.2511-mdk, APPDATA=C:\Users\Sebastian\AppData\Roaming, JAVA_EXE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_181/bin/java.exe, CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files, Path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Gradle\gradle-5.1.1\bin;C:\Users\Sebastian\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin, OS=Windows_NT, COMPUTERNAME=DESKTOP-67RGPD7, PROCESSOR_REVISION=0203, CLASSPATH=C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\Modding\forge\forge-1.10.2-12.18.3.2511-mdk\\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.jar, CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files, ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe, APP_BASE_NAME=gradlew, SystemRoot=C:\Windows, TEMP=C:\Users\SEBAST~1\AppData\Local\Temp, HOMEDRIVE=C:, USERPROFILE=C:\Users\Sebastian, TMP=C:\Users\SEBAST~1\AppData\Local\Temp, CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files, NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=4, sourcesdk=C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\SourceSDK}

16:52:49.249 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: STARTING

16:52:49.251 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Waiting until process started: Gradle build daemon.

16:52:49.266 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: STARTED

16:52:49.266 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner] waiting until streams are handled...

16:52:49.266 [INFO] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Successfully started process 'Gradle build daemon'

16:52:49.267 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonOutputConsumer] Starting 
consuming the daemon process output.

16:52:49.267 [DEBUG] 
[org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter] Gradle daemon process is starting. Waiting for the daemon to detach...

16:52:49.354 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonOutputConsumer] daemon out: Error occurred during initialization of VM

16:52:49.354 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonOutputConsumer] daemon out: Could not reserve enough space for 3145728KB object heap

16:52:49.359 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: DETACHED

16:52:49.361 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'Gradle build daemon' finished with exit value 0 (state: DETACHED)

16:52:49.361 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter] Gradle daemon process is now detached.

16:52:49.362 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter] An attempt to start the daemon took 0.14 secs.

16:52:49.369 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]

16:52:49.369 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

16:52:49.369 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]

16:52:49.370 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:

16:52:49.370 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/2.14/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

Please read the following process output to find out more:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
16:52:49.370 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Could not reserve enough space for 3145728KB object heap
16:52:49.370 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
16:52:49.370 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
16:52:49.371 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
16:52:49.371 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
```

Comment: Remove the 32 bit version of Java. It's the culprit, limiting gradle to only 2G. Additionally, check how much memory you are allocating to gradle. Around `-Xmx2G` should be enough

Comment: After I removed 32Bit Java, it still didn't work. When I set Xmx to 1G it started to setup the Workspace